# Sampling of non-baseband signals - Shannon sampling theorem

Tags: sampling

In the example on Sampling of non-basedband signals on Wikipedia,
[image]

the author said it is sufficient to sample at 4 MHz (twice the width of the frequency interval). But how did the author calculate the width of the frequency interval which in that case is equal to 2? Any explanations to how he came up with 4MHz

[Wikipedia - Shannon sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#Sampling_of_non-baseband_signals)

Comment: read the example (last para) - frequency range 100 - 102 Mhz,  Need to sample at twice the bandwidth of 2MHz and so sample at twice that  frequency = 4Mhz (i.e. the Nyquist criterion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text explicitly says "signals in the frequency range of 100-102 MHz". The bandwidth is the difference between the maximum and minimum frequencies: 102 MHz - 100 MHz = 2 MHz